# Resuming queued jobs after NodeJS worker restart on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, rabbitmq, jobs, sigterm

So I have a fairly simple setup on *Heroku*. I'm using *RabbitMQ* for handling background jobs. My setup consists of a node script that runs daily using *Heroku Scheduler* addon. The scripts adds jobs to the queue, the worker in turn, consumes them and delegates them onto a separate module for handling.

The problem starts after I receive a **SIGTERM** event that *Heroku* initiates randomly from time to time, before restarting the instance.

For some reason, after the instance is restarted, the worker is never get back up again. Only when I restart it manually by doing `heroku ps:scale worker=0` and `heroku ps:scale worker=1` The worker continues to consume the pending jobs.

Here's my worker:

```
// worker.js
var throng = require('throng');
var jackrabbit = require('jackrabbit');
var logger = require('logfmt');
var syncService = require('./syncService');

var start = function () {
    var queue = jackrabbit(process.env.RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_RX_URL || 'amqp://localhost');

    logger.log({type: 'msg', msg: 'start', service: 'worker'});

     queue
        .default()
        .on('drain', onDrain)
        .queue({name: 'syncUsers'})
        .consume(onMessage)

    function onMessage(data, ack, nack) {

        var promise;
        switch (data.type) {
            case 'updateUser':
                promise = syncService.updateUser(data.target, data.source);
                break;
            case 'createUser':
                promise = syncService.createUser(data.source);
                break;
            case 'deleteUser':
                promise = syncService.deleteUser(data.target);
        }

        promise.then(ack, nack);
    }

    function onDrain() {
        queue.close();
        logger.log({type: 'info', msg: 'sync complete', service:    'worker'});
     }

    process.on('SIGTERM', shutdown);


    function shutdown() {
        logger.log({type: 'info', msg: 'shutting down'});
        queue.close();
        process.exit();
    }

};


throng({
    workers: 1,
    lifetime: Infinity,
    grace: 4000
}, start);
```

Comment: what are you seeing in the log files from heroku, after the SIGTERM happens? are you getting the "shutting down" message? what about on the RMQ side - after SIGTERM shuts down the heroku process, does RMQ show messages in "unacked" state? are you seeing connections and channels still open?

Comment: No "shutting down" message just "Stopping all processes with SIGTERM"
then "Process exited with status 0".

Answer (score 1):

The `close()` method on the `jackrabbit` object [takes a callback](https://github.com/hunterloftis/jackrabbit/blob/d43d0919359bfd4ddad469d1dbff80aa4b716a20/lib/jackrabbit.js#L35-L48), you should avoid exiting the process until that is finished:

```
function shutdown() {
    logger.log({type: 'info', msg: 'shutting down'});
    queue.close(function (e) {
      process.exit(e ? 1 : 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks. can you explain how this is related to why rabbitmq doesn't resume to process the reminding jobs?